# Mysql query with multiple selects results in high CPU load

Tags: mysql, multiple-select, multiple-select-query

I'm trying to do a link exchange script and run into a bit of trouble.
Each link can be visited by an IP address a number of x times (frequency in links table). Each visit costs a number of credits (spend limit given in limit in links table)

I've got the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contor` (
`key` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`uniqueHandler` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`uniqueLink` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`uniqueUser` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`owner` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`credits` float NOT NULL,
`tstamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
KEY `uniqueLink` (`uniqueLink`),
KEY `uniqueHandler` (`uniqueHandler`),
KEY `uniqueUser` (`uniqueUser`),
KEY `owner` (`owner`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
`unique` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
`frequency` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`limit` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`unique`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've got the following query:

```
$link = MYSQL_QUERY("
    SELECT * 
    FROM `links` 
    WHERE (SELECT count(key) FROM contor WHERE ip = '$ip' AND contor.uniqueLink = links.unique) <= `frequency` 
    AND (SELECT sum(credits) as cost FROM contor WHERE contor.uniqueLink = links.unique) <= `limit`")
```

There are 20 rows in the table links.

The problem is that whenever there are about 200k rows in the table contor the CPU load is huge.

After applying the solution provided by @Barmar:
Added composite index on (uniqueLink, ip) and droping all other indexes except PRIMARY, EXPLAIN gives me this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     l   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18  
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    15  
2   DERIVED     pop_contor  index   NULL    contor_IX1  141     NULL    206122
```

Comment: Is it correct that `sum(credits)` doesn't use `WHERE ip = '$ip'`?

Comment: @Barmar. It is correct, sum(credits) doesn't use WHERE ip = '$ip'

Comment: This is a security nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a join rather than a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT l.*
FROM links AS l
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT uniqueLink, SUM(ip = '$ip') AS ip_visits, SUM(credits) AS total_credits
    FROM contor
    GROUP BY uniqueLink
) AS c
ON c.uniqueLink = l.unique AND ip_visits <= frequency AND total_credits <= limit
```

If this doesn't help, try adding an index on `contor.ip`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar the join seems to have reduced load on the server. However.. You have had 52298 queries where a join could not use an index properly

Indexes in contor:
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
  KEY `contor_IX1` (`uniqueLink`,`credits`,`ip`)

Indexes in links:

  PRIMARY KEY (`unique`),
  KEY `unique` (`unique`,`frequency`,`limit`),

Comment: A composite index on `(uniqueLink, ip)` might help with that.

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, that's impossible to read.

Comment: If `contor_IX1` is the composite index, I think that showed it's being used to do the grouping in the subquery. Unfortunately, derived tables don't get their own indexes, so the join can't be indexed. You might be able to fix that by creating a temporary table with the result of the subquery, index it, and then join. But unless you can reuse the temporary table in multiple joins, it's essentially the same total work.

Answer (score 1):

The current query is of the form:

```
 SELECT l.* 
   FROM `links` l
  WHERE l.frequency >= ( SELECT COUNT(ck.key)
                           FROM contor ck
                          WHERE ck.uniqueLink = l.unique
                            AND ck.ip = '$ip' 
                       )
    AND l.limit     >= ( SELECT SUM(sc.credits) 
                           FROM contor sc
                          WHERE sc.uniqueLink = l.unique 
                       )
```

Those correlated subqueries are going to each your lunch. And your lunchbox too.

I'd suggest testing an inline view that performs both of the aggregations from `contor` in one pass, and then join the result from that to the `links` table.
Something like this:

```
 SELECT l.*
   FROM ( SELECT c.uniqueLink
               , SUM(c.ip = '$ip' AND c.key IS NOT NULL) AS count_key
               , SUM(c.credits)                          AS sum_credits
            FROM `contor` c
           GROUP
              BY c.uniqueLink
        ) d
   JOIN `links` l
     ON l.unique     = d.uniqueLink
    AND l.frequency >= d.count_key
    AND l.limit     >= d.sum_credits
```

For optimal performance of the aggregation inline view query, provide a covering index that MySQL can use to optimize the GROUP BY (avoiding a Using filesort operation)

```
  CREATE INDEX `contor_IX1` ON `contor` (`uniqueLink`, `credits`, `ip`) ;
```

Adding that index renders the `uniqueLink` index redundant, so also...

```
  DROP INDEX `uniqueLink` ON `contor` ;
```

---

**EDIT**

Since we have a guarantee that `contor.key` column is non-NULL (i.e. the `NOT NULL` constraint), this part of the query above is unneeded `AND c.key IS NOT NULL`, and can be removed. (I also removed the `key` column from the covering index definition above.)

```
 SELECT l.*
   FROM ( SELECT c.uniqueLink
               , SUM(c.ip = '$ip')  AS count_key
               , SUM(c.credits)     AS sum_credits
            FROM `contor` c
           GROUP
              BY c.uniqueLink
        ) d
   JOIN `links` l
     ON l.unique     = d.uniqueLink
    AND l.frequency >= d.count_key
    AND l.limit     >= d.sum_credits
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON l.frequency >= d.count_key AND l.limit >= d.sum_credits LIMIT 0, 30' at line 11
Server version: 5.5.54-0+deb7u1-log (Debian)

Comment: *DOH!*. That second `ON` keyword should be replaced with an `AND` keyword. (Correction is applied to the SQL in the answer.)

Comment: Now I understand what the effects of sleep deprivation are. Going on 72 hours only on caffeine and crisps :) Thank you @spencer7593